# Attach attributes in a separate table to a layer on GeoServer

Tags: django-models, postgis, geoserver

I have an Occurrence model, which is represented by a polygon, and has a one-to-many relationship to an attribute table. The models are stored in a PostGIS database.

```
class Occurrence(models.Model):
    """Model representing an archaeological occurrence within a site."""
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    bounding_polygon = models.PolygonField(null=True, blank=True)
    #...
```

```
class AttributeOccurrence(models.Model):
    """Model representing an attribute of an occurrence."""
    value = models.ForeignKey(AttributeChoice, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    occurrence = models.ForeignKey(Occurrence, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have created a Store in GeoServer to publish the layer for the Occurrences.

How can I associate these attributes that are in the table so that they can be visible through GeoServer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the [application schema](https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/data/app-schema/index.html) extension:

> The application schema support (app-schema) extension provides support for [Complex Features](https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/data/app-schema/complex-features.html#app-schema-complex-features) in GeoServer WFS.